# Как сделать таймаут при чтении из udp::socket в boost::asio?

Tags: отладка, асинхронность, c++17, boost.asio

Я создаю однопоточное приложение, которое обменивается данными по UDP с другим. Когда второе отключается, то socket::receive_from блокируется и я не знаю, как решить эту проблему не переводя программу целиком на многопоточность или асинхронные взаимодействия.

Я думал, что следующий код может быть решением:

```
    std::chrono::milliseconds timeout{4};
    boost::system::error_code err;
    data_t buffer(kPackageMaxSize);
    std::size_t size = 0;

    const auto status = std::async(std::launch::async,
        [&]{
            size = socket_.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), dst_, 0, err);
        }
    ).wait_for(timeout);

    switch (status)
    {
        case std::future_status::timeout: /*...*/ break;
    }
```

Но я встретился с новой проблемой: Qt Creator (GDB 11.1) (у меня пока нет возможности использовать что-то другое) начал падать, когда я пытаюсь дебажить. Если без дебагера запускать, то решение работает не всегда.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Следует использовать асинхронное чтение и одновременно устанавливать асинхронный таймер с нужным временем ожидания, который должен будет завершать операцию с asio::error::timed_out.

Comment: user7860670, спасибо. Можно, пожалуйста, пример кода?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.timeouts